# why code displaying on browser while running php script using tomcat 6.0

Tags: php, tomcat, tomcat6

i am trying to run php script using apache tomcat6.0. am using netbeans as my editor. there is no errors while running and got a message build succesfull. i have two programs welcome.php and form.jsp. the form.jsp is used for user entry form and its displaying on the browser. but when i submit the form the welcome.php is not working and its giving me program code on browser. this is my welcome.php.

```
    $query1="select * from company";
    $result1 = odbc_exec($connect, $query1);

   #fetch the data from the database
    while(odbc_fetch_row($result1)){
     $cnamearray[$count] = odbc_result($result1, 1);
   $enamearray[$count] = odbc_result($result1, 2);

   if($cnamearray[$count]==$_POST['cname'])
  {
     print "<script> alert(\"cname Exists\"); </script>";
    exit();
   }

 if($enamearray[$count]==$_POST['ename'])
   {
 print "<script> alert(\"eName Exists\"); </script>";
 exit();
   }
   }
   $query=("INSERT INTO company(cname,ename) VALUES ('$_POST[cname]','$_POST[ename]') ");
 $result = odbc_exec($connect, $query);
echo "<script> alert(\"Row Inserted\"); </script>";

 ?>
```

am getting

```
 "; exit(); } if($enamearray[$count]==$_POST['ename']) { print ""; exit(); } }
 $query=("INSERT     INTO company(cname,ename) VALUES ('$_POST[cname]','$_POST
  [ename]') ");        
 $result = odbc_exec($connect, $query); echo ""; ?>
```

these codes on browser.

why the codes are displaying on the browser . what i must do to get output. how can i run php script in tomcat

Answer (score 3):

Tomcat by itself is a Java servlet/JSP container, and knows nothing about PHP -- you realize that, right? You need to do some sort of unholy hack to get PHP working on Tomcat. [Here](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/UsingPhp) is a Google hit for "Tomcat PHP", and it looks like it does indeed describe just such a hack.

May Cthulhu have mercy on your soul.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to add a closing quotation mark and semi-colon to your $query1 line

```
$query1="select * from company
```

Should be...

```
 $query1="select * from company";
```

Comment: he'd be getting a php error and not the source code if this was the error. Ernest's answer is the more likely problem.